# Connecting to LocalDb

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Can anybody point me to resources that will allow me to connect to a local Database (SQL Server) to allow me to update a table from unit tests.

My connection String Below

```
string Server ="(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database = TestDB; Integrated Security = True";
```

getting Closer

I Can Now connect to the DB

```
 public static void sqlserver()
    {
        string connetionString;

        SqlConnection cnn;

        connetionString = @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True";
        //connetionString = @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";
        //connetionString = "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);


        SqlCommand command;
        string sql = "UPDATE TestRun SET Date = GETDATE()";
        //sql = "UPDATE TestRun SET Date = GETDATE()";
        string sqlsearch = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TestRun";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        //command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

        cnn.Open();
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        command.ExecuteScalar();
        //Console.WriteLine(sqlsearch);
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

But its not putting the data into the table

All I need now is the sql/tsql statement
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted

first Issue I had to create a data connection to the DB from server explorer This is wrong.

I created a new DB in server Explorer data Connections

the working code is:

```
public static void sqlserver()
    {
        string connetionString;
        SqlConnection cnn;

        connetionString = "Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\TestDB\\Documents\\test.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        SqlCommand command;
        string sql = "INSERT INTO TestRun (Date,Message) VALUES (GETDATE(),'SQL Server Attempt Passed')";
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

        cnn.Open();
        command.ExecuteReader();
        cnn.Close();
        cnn.Dispose();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Removed Unnecessary repeated line, also tidied it up a bit.